# Why is the sculpt tool snapping to my mesh's vertices?

Tags: vertices, snapping, sculpt

I have a mesh. I am trying to sculpt it, but the tool keeps jumping around, snapping itself to the mesh's vertices. I don't have snapping on. Reset brush doesn't fix it. What causes this?
[image]